# Enviar metodos dentro de un httpost Error de instancia

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo un servicio de pagos y quiero que cuando se valide que una tarjeta exista este llame a otro servicio que registra datos en una tabla.

Este es el controlador

```
public class PagoController : ApiController
    {
        ValidarPagoNegocios negocios = new ValidarPagoNegocios();
        [HttpPost]
        public ValidarPagoResponse ValidarPago(ValidarPagoRequest request) {
            ValidarPagoResponse response = new ValidarPagoResponse();
            string mensaje = "";
            response.TransaccionCompleta 
                =  negocios.ValidarPago(out mensaje,
                                        request.TipoTarjeta,request.NumeroTarjeta,
                                        request.TitularTarjeta, request.MontoConsumir,
                                        request.MesExpiracionTarjeta,request.AñoExpiracionTarjeta,
                                        request.CodigoSeguridadTarjeta);
            response.TransaccionMensaje = mensaje;
             return response;
        }
```

Esta es la respuesta del postman cuando la tarjeta esta validada

```
"TransaccionCompletada" : true 
"TransaccionMensaje" : " "
```

intente hacerlo de esta manera pero me aparece un mensaje de error de : Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto señalando todo el metodo

```
TutoriaNegocios negocios2 = new TutoriaNegocios();

        ValidarPagoNegocios negocios = new ValidarPagoNegocios();
        [HttpPost]
        public ValidarPagoResponse ValidarPago(ValidarPagoRequest request)
        {
            ValidarPagoResponse response = new ValidarPagoResponse();
            string mensaje = negocios2.matriculaTutoria(request.matricula);
            response.TransaccionCompleta
                = negocios.ValidarPago(out mensaje,
                                        request.TipoTarjeta, request.NumeroTarjeta,
                                        request.TitularTarjeta, request.MontoConsumir,
                                        request.MesExpiracionTarjeta, request.AñoExpiracionTarjeta,
                                        request.CodigoSeguridadTarjeta,request.matricula.idAlumno,request.matricula.idTutoria);
            response.TransaccionMensaje = mensaje;
            return response;
        }
```

las clases que toma de parametros son estas:

```
public class ValidarPagoResponse
    {
        public bool TransaccionCompleta { get; set; }
        public string TransaccionMensaje { get; set; }
    }



 public class ValidarPagoRequest
    {

        public string NumeroTarjeta { get; set; }
        public int TipoTarjeta { get; set; }
        public string CodigoSeguridadTarjeta { get; set; }
        public string TitularTarjeta { get; set; }
        public string MesExpiracionTarjeta { get; set; }
        public string AñoExpiracionTarjeta { get; set; }
        public double MontoConsumir { get; set; }
        public MatriculaViewModel matricula { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: no puedes poner un breakpoint en el action he inspeccionar que variable esta quedando en null ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista lo que me genera sospecha la propiedad `matricula` de `ValidarPagoRequest` este sin asignar, por eso cuando accedes a sus propiedades tengas el fallo

Para solucionar el problema podrias instanciar la propiedad en el constructor

```
public class ValidarPagoRequest
{
    public ValidarPagoRequest()
    {
        this.matricula = new MatriculaViewModel();
    }

    public string NumeroTarjeta { get; set; }
    public int TipoTarjeta { get; set; }
    public string CodigoSeguridadTarjeta { get; set; }
    public string TitularTarjeta { get; set; }
    public string MesExpiracionTarjeta { get; set; }
    public string AñoExpiracionTarjeta { get; set; }
    public double MontoConsumir { get; set; }
    public MatriculaViewModel matricula { get; set; }
}
```

Pero en realidad lo que deberias validar es porque el cliente que invoca al servicio no esta enviando los datos de forma correcta de la matricula

Tambien se podria valida con algo como ser

```
[HttpPost]
public ValidarPagoResponse ValidarPago(ValidarPagoRequest request)
{       
    if(request.matricula == null)
        throw new Exception("debe asignar los datos de la matricula");

    //resto codigo
}
```